# RC Lowpass Filter between Amplifier and ADC input

Tags: amplifier, adc, filter, instrumentation-amplifier, passive-filter

I have sensors (pyranometers that consist of thermopiles and measure sun irradiation) that ouput a low voltage signal so I need to amplify them using an instrumentation amplifier.

I have chosen the AD8237 for this task: [Datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8237.pdf)

I'm using a gain of 100 to amplify the initial low voltage signal (ranging 0-20mV) to 0-2V range.

I'm then feeding the amplified signal to the ADC (MCP3422): [Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/22088c.pdf)

My sensor values change very slowly and I will read out the digitized ADC values only once every second, so speed is not important in my case.

Now as pointed out in the accepted answer in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/412250/amplifier-with-true-ground-output-swing-and-a-d-conversion/412364?noredirect=1#comment1034983_412364) I need a filter between the IN-Amp and the ADC to filter the noise.
In many ADC-datasheets a simple passive RC-filter is suggested between the INA and ADC.
I did quite some research and I still have some questions that confuse me and I hope you can help me with:

I figured that a first order RC filter does not meet my requirements so I cascaded multiple RC stages:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fApVmO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And this is the simulated filter response in LTSpice:
[image: rc_filter]

**Questions:**

- Can I do that?
- What would be the disadvantages using the proposed filter?
- Capacitor values like 47µF or even 100µF give me a even better response (stronger attenuation,) would that have a negative impact on my signal or the ADC?

I guess resistor values should not be further increased to prevent voltage drop on my signal.

The filter response seems very promising:

Signals at 10Hz already attenuated by ~50% and at 25Hz already by ~90%. As I only care about the DC signal I guess that response should be fine (also 50-60Hz range is covered strongly by the filter.)

Resistors create voltage drops so how would these three cascaded resistors affect my amplified signal (thus my digitized value calculated by the ADC?)

Ohms law should apply, but I do not know the current...
Any clarification on this is highly appreciated.

Regarding speed/time constants:

As my data acquisition (readout ADC once per second) and change in sensor value is very slow, do I need to keep an eye on the speed/time constant of this filter?

As many datasheets suggest an RC filter stage this approach should not be too far off.

Comment: why not use LC filters?

Comment: mainly because I had to choose very very large values for L to get the same attenuation in the low Hz region. Feel free to suggest a configuration, I appreciate any help I can get! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This 3-section RC should provide better rolloff at high frequencies. The random noise is dominated by that 3,000,000 ohm resistor with the 5Hz bandwidth, less than 1uV RMS.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOD9d0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is what Signal Chain Explorer (we used that to predict Gargoyles interferer levels)
shows as the 3-pole rolloff. With 2 volts PP input, the ENOB is 19.7

[image]

Notice we are NOT including ANY ADC noise contributions.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) To make sure: I assume the box (including the 3pF cap and FET and R4) is modeling the ADC? Simulation of your filter in LTSpice is very promising, Im wondering how did you come up with the initial values? Hope you will share your approach. Do I see it right that this filtering will not have any negative inpact/voltage drop on my desired DC signal?

Comment: The leftmost value is chosen to be a light load on the INA. Other resistors are simply scaled up 10X and 100X, to be light loads on the prior RC section, so the far-out attenuation is indeed 60dB/decade. The ADC **must** draw some charge. Rumor tells us there will be a DC voltage drop across the resistors. 3pF and 3volts and 1,000 sample/second have I = F * C * V = 9 nanoAmps **average** current; thru that 3MegOhm final resistor, the average DC offset will be 27 microVolts. To reduce, use 10Kohm, 47Kohm, 270Kohm.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks! Could you please tell me if Dmitry Grigoryev in his answer is right and I have to use at least 10-100 kOhm in the RC-filter? Would it be a problem to use only one stage of a single pole RC-filter with 1 kOhm and 10µF for testing. Could I damage my instrumentation amplifier with that?

Comment: One more question: what are the most severe consequences of not scaling cascaded RC resitors up in value? Would love to hear your knowledge on that :)

Answer (score 9):

If you are reading the ADC just once per second then you need to eliminate frequencies above **0.5 Hz** to prevent aliasing. If you think your system will have noise at, say 10 Hz, then that noise will contaminate your readings. I recommend that you sample at a much higher rate, perhaps some multiple of the power mains frequency, and perform low-pass filtering in software. Even a simple moving-average filter would work and wouldn't take much processing.

Comment: So I could use the proposed filter in case I read out e.g. 10 times per second and perform averaging of these 10 values I got out of the ADC in software?

Comment: If you sample at 10 times per second then all of the frequencies above 5 Hz in your input signal will be aliased. Is the noise content in your signal above 5 Hz low enough that you can live with the error due to aliasing? Only you can answer that question.

Comment: In order to use the 18Bit resolution mode, one has to set the ADC to 3.75 SPS (and I would read once per second, but I guess only the 3.75 samples per second rate is important here. Does it make a difference that im dealing with a delta sigma ADC here?). I'm a bit confused as I only need the DC signal (and that has no frequency?) so this aliasing issue still applies to me? If I use a modified version of the filter proposed above, with resistor values 1k and values for the caps 47µF I get an attenuation of ~-15dB at 3 Hz, so I should be fine in that case?

Comment: Your statements are inconsistent. If you only need the dc signal then you only need to sample the signal **once** and never again. If you sample every second then it must be because the signal is **changing**, therefore it is not a dc signal. Furthermore, your signal will be noisy and this noise is an ac signal. So, your signal is an ac signal, not a dc signal. Therefore, you need to think about aliasing. The ADC does have an internal filter (see 4.7 in the datasheet) but it may not be enough...

Comment: But **only you** really know what your signal looks like and **only you** know what accuracy your system requires...for whatever reason you have not shared this information with us. Consequently, **no one else** can tell you what sort of filter would be "good enough".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The sensors are pyranometers that consist of thermopiles and measure sun irradiation. They output a low voltage signal (between 0-20mV) depending on the sun irradiation present. So this value really changes very very slowly as you can imagine. I sample every second or so only in order to get a time series (but not because the sensor output is changing that fast). Can you make any more statements or give me more precise feedback with that info? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Any frequency component in your signal, whether from noise in the system or birds flying in front of your sensor, that has a frequency of 0.5Hz  or higher will cause errors in your data. It's as simple as that. How much noise will you have? Only you know. How much error can you tolerate? Only you know.

Comment: Sensors provide a DC signal. But there is noise to be expected from the instrumentation amplifier, so i want to get rid of that before I send it into the ADC. Especially 10-100kHz should be filtered to get rid of switching noise. I can not tell exactly how much noise there will be without prototyping it first so I want to make sure I have all the components I need in case a filter in front of the ADC input is required. I want to get as much noise filtered as possible with the proposed configuration. But do oyu know if the proposed configuratino would work or do you see issues with it? thanks!

Comment: @ElliotAlderson so the higher the data rate the better when samplig a DC signal?

Comment: @bardulia When sampling a DC signal you only need to sample one time. If the signal is DC it will not change so there is never a need to sample it again.

Answer (score 2):

ADC inputs typically are quite high impedance. I have often used 100K in series with an input with no dc loss. (and a capacitor to ground for filtering) If you are happy with the attenuation with that circuit then I would suggest scaling the resistors up and the capacitors down. I would not use electrolytic capacitors as they tend to have more leakage compared to other types. I would probably use a ceramic cap.

Edit:

I just looked at the data sheet for the part. Go take a look at page 3, Input Impedance. Loading certainly will not be an issue.

Comment: Ok so you suggest I could increase the values of the resistors but in general there should not be any problems using this filter in my configuration? I'm a bit confused as the answers by Dmitry Grigoryev and Elliot Alderson indicate problems with the current filter configuration. Could you please make a comment on that? (Do you see the same problems as the two answers I named?). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The ADC input will look like a SHORT, for 5 or 10 nanoSeconds, at beginning of the Sample time. That "short" will disrupt any opamp directly connected to the ADC Vin or the ADC VREF.

To prevent this "disruption" (which shows up as ringing, and perhaps input-voltage-dependent quantization errors, we can place LARGE capacitors on the Vin and the VREF pins.

Assume the ADC has 10pF capacitors on its Vin and VREF pins, and assume these capacitors have had their charge consumed during the just-prior ADC operation.

As the ADC once again grabs some charge, there will be surge currents demanded from the external voltage sources(Vin and/or VREF).

To minimize the voltage upset, use LARGE external capacitors: 100X or 1,000X or 10,000X larger than the ADC sample (10pF) capacitors.

In the 3-cascaded_RC filter I gave you, that final capacitor is 10nF (10,000 pF) and should work well.

Again, if the AVERAGE input current is 9nanoAmps (Vin of 3 volts, Cap is 3pF, Fsample being 1,000 per second), flowing thru 3,000,000 ohms, there will be an error of 27 milliVolts. This will show up as a linear gain error.
[ ERROR this had been 27 microVolts]

Comment: I got back to this interesting topic and hope you can help me once again: if I use a single pole RC LPF in front of this ADC (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/22088c.pdf) with R=100kOhm and C=4.7uF i get a bigger voltage drop (about 60mV drop for Vin=1.5V). I did measurements and this error is linear. Could you give me some hints how I would calculate the average input current for this ADC in particular? Im confused due to the delta/sigma ADC. I know it oversamples so not sure what to take as the frequency. If I use the 18bit setting with 3.75SPS for example. Thank you.

Comment: You made a mistake I guess, with 3M resistor the voltage offset would be 27 **millivolts**, NOT 27 microvolts.

Comment: Henry Thanks for finding that mistake. And regarding the (internal) sampling frequency, datasheets may or may not tell you. If they do not tell you the Fsample (not the Fconversion, which is 3.75Hz) and the Input Sampling Capacitance (the ESD capacitance is not part of this), then the datasheet needs to tell you the Equivalent Input resistance.

Answer (score 2):

Forget the filter entirely. It's a waste of time. You have a uC at your disposal, so simply take multiple samples (10x, 100x.. as many as feasible) and average the result. That'll get rid of any a/c and/or noise.

Answer (score 1):

Your filter will effectively short out the amp if the signal has any significant AC component (even around mains frequency and first/second harmonic). Check out the datasheet: your amp has 4 mA *short current* and response characteristics are measured with loads of 10-100 kOhm. The equivalent resistance of your filter must be at least that big.

Comment: So the series resistance of my filter (in this case the resistance of the 3 cascaded resistors) must be at least 10kOhm? So the current drawn from the In-amp is limited and does not get too high? Would such a high resistance not heavily impact my signal?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this issue? What effect would it have on my circuit in case I use the proposed filter? Thank you.

Comment: @Henry I'm talking about the resistance from amp output to ground, not to ADC input. Even if we consider only R1 and C1, the resistance is 200 + 100 (at 100 Hz) = 300 Ohm, which is way too low.

Comment: I dont get the problem to be honest. I want the resistance to be low after the IN-Amp output (the ADC input has high input impedance) in the signal trace dont I? And I want to short AC to ground also. What would you change in the said configuration, could you name the values you would use? Thank you!

Comment: How much resistance do I need at least? How can I determine the value?

Comment: @Henry Yes, you want the resistance to be as low as possible, but you're limited by what your amplifier can deliver. Check out the datasheet of AD8237, specifically figures 61 & 62. Do these make sense? 300 Ohm would be completely out of spec, and 1kOhm would give you very poor voltage swing. You need **at least 10kOhm** of load resistance.

Comment: OK thank you very much for pointing that out! However, im still a bit confused: The ADC input has more than 10kOhm input impedance. So that should already be enough? By adding the filter I even increase the resistance here. I get that I also add caps that are connected to ground but they will not let thru any DC voltage so im not seeing any problem here. I would really appreciate it if you could try to explain this to me one more time (would be happy if you could do that by editing your answer so also other people will easily see it). Thank you very much :)

Comment: ADC input is high impedance and poses no problem. The primary contributor to low resistance is your RC filter. Again: a 22µF capacitor has an equivalent resistance of 100 Ohm at 100Hz. If your signal has a significant AC component, you will overload the amplifier.

Comment: ok, thank you. But I think that should be ok if my sensors change very slowly (response to change is at least 18 seconds but irradiation changes a lot slower than that). So even if some noise is introduced by the amplifier the major part should still be DC and not shorted to GND right? How would you define 'significant AC component'. If I check the INA output signal, how could I make sure that this is still enough DC component?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Elliot - a little different approach could be to sample/hold, sort of a Nyquist filter where you pick the best over-sample frequency to get rid of the most prevalent noise. I've done that with RTDs in a noisy aircraft and it gave me good results.  I was dealing with millivolt changes that had to be very accurate.  That gets rid of those big caps and the insertion loss from the resistors that you are concerned about.

I just threw this together in LTspice to give you the idea... if you want the source I will send it. I made the input the 2 volts which would include the amplifier in your design. I added 50Hz and some random HF noise riding on top of that.
[image: Simulation of filter - LTspice]

The filter uses active components except for the R/C tweak with filter 3.  Implementation is up to the designer but this can be done with tiny parts, 2x2 to 4x4mm for most active and 0402s for the rest. I think that's smaller than the passive parts but if RE is important an area study is necessary. I just show a switch (S/H) for the concept. Once implemented a value change or two will adjust the sample rate.

From a practical viewpoint, the input is almost DC with such slow fluctuations.  The noise is much faster and random with respects to the fixed sample rate so it averages out.  The assumption is that the noise excursions fluctuate around zero, typical of differential coupling.  I used this with RTDs which are slower and in an aircraft environment which is noisy (it qualified MIL-STD-461).  It seems like it would do a good job for this source as well, but will take some tinkering based on the real world.

I displayed the parameters on the schematic so you can lift them if you use LTspice.

Comment: sounds good, can you elaborate on this approach or link me to an example (maybe provide a small example circuit yourself with brief explanation) as I do not understand your approach well yet, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your input! Interesting, source would be nice so I can play around a bit. But you are using active components in the filters as well? Or do I misunderstand your approach here?