# Are there any benefits to amplify the signal for this case?

Tags: amplifier, data-acquisition

A force transducer together with its amplifier designed for a full scale load such that it has -5V to +5V range as output. But it is only used with loads outputting -200mV to +200mV. A data acquisition ADC is sampling the output voltages.

The ADC input range is -10 to +10V and its resolution is 16 bit.

Are there any benefits to amplify the transducer output in this case? Could you give me a practical example.

(I guess SNR will not improve because noise will be amplified as well)

Comment: *I guess SNR will not improve because noise will be amplified as well* That is only true if the noise of the transducer is dominant. But what if the (quantization) noise of the ADC is dominant ? That can be the case if the ADC's input signal is quite small.

Comment: Is that the only possible benefit?Would matching the input to the ADC range have any benefit? I just could not explain why.

Comment: "Matching the input to the ADC range" is exactly what Bimpelrekkie recommends in the quantization-dominated regime; maybe read up on ADCs and quantization!

Comment: *I just could not explain why.* Simple! Just think about an extreme case: 16-bit ADC with +/- 10 V input range but my signal is only +/- 0.1 V. that +/- 10 V = 20 V is divided in 20 / (2^16) = 305 uV steps. So +/- 0.1 V = 0.2 V is divided in 0.2 V / 305 uV = 655 steps. 16 bit means 2^16 = 65536 steps. So I'm using about 1% of the steps. If I would properly use a **10 bit ADC** (instead of 16 bit) I could get a **better** result than using the 16 bit ADC. An ADC is only used **to the max** if you really use almost all the bits!

Comment: **IF** you **need** the high resolution, you can either amplify to fit the full-scale ADC input range. Or you can buy a higher-resolution ADC. You still have the responsibility to keep electric fields and magnetic fields and Ground trash out of the ADC input.

Comment: Depends on where you amplify, and how much interference gets coupled into any cable running from Sensor to the Amplifier.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a similar question, with 0.02 volt sensor into a 100X amplifier. Thus 2 volts output to the ADC, but in an assumed high-interference setup.
The conclusion is to ADD a LOWPASS RC filter before the ADC.

Go to this question, and scroll down past the question, and read the answer by "analogsystemsrf"

[RC Lowpass Filter between Amplifier and ADC input](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/418009/rc-lowpass-filter-between-amplifier-and-adc-input/418027#418027)

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment, or a vote to mark as duplicate?